# In LibreOffice the "recent files" shows "no documents"

Tags: libreoffice

in my LibreOffice the menu item **recent files** (in german "Zuletzt verwendete Dokumente") shows **no documents** ("keine Dokumente"), although I have used several docs.

I searched online and found the settings at **Extras-->Options--> Advanced-->Expert Settings** (Extras-->Optionen-->Erweitert-->Experteneinstellungen) **org.openoffice.Office.Common --> History**:

Size shows 100 and PicklistSize shows 25.

Even in **org.openoffice.Office.Histories:HistoriesOrder['n']** (n from 1 to 24) the correct filenames appear.

That seems to be normal. I tried to delete the profile in `~/.config/libreoffice/4` by renaming it. A new profile is built, but with the same problem.

Can anyone help?

I use Ubuntu LTS 16.04 with the built-in LibreOffice 5.1.6.2.

Comment: This issue is off-topic. See this: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/78302/when-i-open-liboffice-no-recent-files-are-listed/

Comment: No, they recommend exactly the steps i already have done (deleting/renaming the profile and setting the PickListSize. In my case it doesnt work. And in general: Why "off-topic???. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Redbob could you clarify why you think this is off topic? Are you suggesting that it's a bug report?

Comment: Your issue is related specifically to LibreOffice, doesn't have any relation to Ubuntu. I just showed to you some place where you should search for solution.

Comment: @Redbob Questions about LibreOffice in Ubuntu are on-topic *even* when not Ubuntu-*specific*. The [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) help pages don't support the claim you've made about Ask Ubuntu's scope, and we have [clear strong consensus](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523) that [such questions are on-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/47). (Even *within* SE, overlapping scopes are [by design](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/14/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/).) If you want this policy *changed*, feel free to post on [meta].

Comment: Ok, I agree with that. But, LukeST, did you made an upgrade of your LibreOffice to 5.3 at least? May this problem be related to something weird at this release. At this issue, they suggest it: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/108468/in-writer-file-recent-documents-none-are-listed/

Comment: Do you have `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`?

Comment: Sorry for waiting so long with my answer. I have one file with this name. The bookmarks referr to something a few days old. I changed the name of that file, but nothing changed.